# Efficient non-greedy method of returning multiple lines between patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
bar 1
 foo 1
  how now
  manchu 50
 foo 2
  brown cow
  manchu 55
 foo 3
  the quick brown
  manchu 1
bar 2
 foo 1
  fox jumped
  manchu 8
 foo 2
  over the
  manchu 20
 foo 3
  lazy dog
  manchu 100
 foo 4
  manchu 5
 foo 5
  manchu 7
bar 3
bar 4
```

I want to search 'manchu 55' and receive:

> FOONUMBER=2

(The foo # above 'manchu 55')

> BARNUMBER=1

(The bar # above that foo)

> PHRASETEXT="brown cow"

(The text on the line above 'manchu 55')

So I can ultimately output:

> brown cow, bar 1, foo 2.

Thus far I've accomplished this with some really ugly grep code like:

```
FOONUMBER=`grep -e "manchu 55" -e ^" foo" -e ^"bar" | grep -B 1 "manchu 55" | grep "foo" | awk '{print $2}'`

BARNUMBER=`grep -e ^" foo $FOONUMBER" -e ^"bar" | grep -B 1 "foo $FOONUMBER" | grep "bar" | awk '{print $2}'`

PHRASETEXT=`grep -B 1 "manchu 55" | grep -v "manchu 55"`
```

There are 3 problems with this code:

- It makes me cringe because I know it's bad
- It's slow; I have to go through hundreds of thousands of entries and it's taking too long
- sometimes, as in bar 2, foo 4 and 5 in my example, there is no text above the 'manchu'. In this case, it incorrectly returns a foo, which is not what I want.

I suspected I could do this with sed, doing something like:

```
FOONUMBER=`sed -n '/foo/,/manchu 55/p' | grep foo | awk '{print $2}'
```

Unfortunately sed is too greedy. I've been reading on AWK and state machines, which seems like it might be a better way to do this, but I still don't understand it well enough to set it up.

As you may have been able to determine by now, programming is not what I do for a living, but ultimately I have had this thrust upon me. I'm hoping to rewrite what I already have to be more efficient and hopefully not too complicated as some other poor sod without a programming degree will probably end up having to support any changes to it at some future date.

Comment: Don't have time to write it but with awk you would just basically save the last bar and foo and line you saw and spit them out when you hit the target line and clear saved foo when you get a new bar.

Comment: @Eleck Could you write an expected output?

Comment: It's in the OP, see the yellow boxes.

If I search 'manchu 55' I want to be able to return separate variables for the foo # it is under, the bar # that foo is under, and the text within the foo above the 'manchu' line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with awk:

```
awk -v nManchu=55 -v OFS=", " '
  $1 == "bar" {bar = $0}    # store the most recently seen "bar" line
  $1 == "foo" {foo = $0}    # store the most recently seen "foo" line 
  $1 == "manchu" && $2 == nManchu {print prev, bar, foo} 
  {prev = $0}               # remember the previous line
' file
```

outputs

```
  brown cow, bar 1,  foo 2
```

Running with "nManchu=100" outputs

```
  lazy dog, bar 2,  foo 3
```

This has the advantage of only taking a single pass through the file, instead of parsing the file 3 times to get "bar", "foo" and the prev line.

Comment: +1 this is THE way to do what is requested. I might've named the variable "manchuNr" or just "nr" or similar to avoid `$1 == "manchu" && $2 == manchu` being confusing at first glance :-).

Comment: Upvoted, just a side case: manchu 5 (which will print `foo 4, bar 2, foo 4`): I would add a `&& prev !~ /(bar|foo)/` in the print line condition

Comment: Tensibai, good catch, and thanks.

@glenn jackman, this code flies past my existing crap and is working great. After looking at it for a little bit, I think I have a pretty good handle on how it works. I definitely need to hit the books on awk!

Comment: @Tensibai, I did think of that but decided I didn't have to invent requirements for the OP.

Comment: @glennjackman I really do feel it's an Op statement from the last of the 3 problems mentioned with the author solution (unsure I'm clear...)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

```
sed -n '/foo/ { s/.*foo\s*//; h }; /manchu 55/ { x; p }' filename
```

This is very simple:

```
/foo/ {         # if you see a line with "foo" in it,
  s/.*foo\s*//  # isolate the number
  h             # and put it in the hold buffer
}
/manchu 55/ {   # if you see a line with "manchu 55" in it,
  x             # exchange hold buffer and pattern space
  p             # and print the pattern space.
}
```

This will then print the last number seen after a `foo` before the `manchu 55` line. The bar number can be extracted essentially the same way, and for the phrase text you could use

```
 sed -n '/manchu 55/ { x; p }; h'
```

to get the line held before `manchu 55` is seen. Or possibly

```
 sed -n '/manchu 55/ { x; p }; s/^\s*//; h'
```

to remove leading white spaces in such a line.

If you are certain that only one `manchu 55` line exists in the file or you only want the first match, you can replace `x; p` with `x; p; q`. The `q` will then quit directly after the result is printed.

Comment: This is a great series of one-liners for filling each of the variables individually. I'll be using this method elsewhere in my code and I really appreciate the detailed explanation. Since I do know that `manchu 55` exists only once in my file, the quit option definitely shaves a little time off the run time which is critical in my script. Thanks again!